# All possible steiner trees

Tags: python, graph, tree, networkx

In NetworkX I'm given a complete graph of say 6 nodes, which looks like this. 
[image]

Given key nodes = [1, 2, 3] I need to extract all possible Steiner trees.
(By all possible Steiner trees, I mean those Steiner trees where the edge count of each tree is equal and is also the minimum)

However, using the NetworkX function I'm only able to extract one.
[image]

**I need to extract 2 more trees in the given example,
tree2 = [(2, 1), (2, 3)] and
tree3 = [(3, 1), (3, 2)]**

Answer (score 0):

So you are given a complete, unweighted graph and you are looking for all minimum Steiner trees, correct? In this case, you can just consider the subgraph induced by the terminal nodes (the nodes that need to be in the Steiner tree) and look for all spanning trees on this subgraph.

Comment: I agree that this works in this specific case, i.e. a complete unweighted graph. How would a possible solution for any graph look like?

Comment: In general, it is a (NP-) hard problem. Also, it does not work with NetworkX, to start with, because NetworkX will not give you a minimum Steiner tree, but just an approximation. See for example: https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.06696 for an enumeration algorithm

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I noticed this as well and was wondering how you could solve it.